# Target HTML element from CSS

Tags: html, css, iframe

*html:*

```
<iframe id="fr" name="mainframe"> </iframe>
```

*css:*

```
#fr {width: 1025px; height: 600px;
border: 0px;
src: #;}

a {target: ???}
```

I wanted all the links on the page to be opened in an `iframe` and I wanted to make it so in the `css` document. But how do you refer to (or target) a specific `html` element from inside of a `css` code document? What's the syntax? (If there is one: if question marks are the lone problem.)

Comment: You can only do so by adding target="" to the <a>.

Comment: you are using illegal css. `src` and `target` are not CSS they are HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't do it in css but you can set the base target in your head

```
<base target="frame_name">
```

> The HTML  element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document.

more information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base